# Decode and encode unicode characters as '\u####'

Tags: python

I'm attempting to write a python implementation of `java.util.Properties` which has a requirement that unicode characters are written to the output file in the format of `\u####`

(Documentation is here if you are curious, though it isn't important to the question: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)

I basically need something that passes the following test case

```
def my_encode(s):
    # Magic

def my_decode(s):
    # Magic

# Easy ones that are solved by .encode/.decode 'unicode_escape'
assert my_decode('\u2603') == u'☃'
assert my_encode(u'☃') == '\\u2603'

# This one also works with .decode('unicode_escape')
assert my_decode('\\u0081') == u'\x81'
# But this one does not quite produce what I want
assert my_encode(u'\u0081') == '\\u0081' # Instead produces '\\x81'
```

Note that I've tried `unicode_escape` and it comes close but doesn't quite satisfy what I want

I've noticed that `simplejson` does this conversion correctly:

```
>> simplejson.dumps(u'\u0081')
'"\\u0081"'
```

But I'd rather avoid:

1. reinventing the wheel
2. doing some gross substringing of simplejson's output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation you linked to:

> Characters less than `\u0020` and characters greater than `\u007E` in property keys or values are written as `\uxxxx` for the appropriate hexadecimal value `xxxx`.

So, that converts into Python readily as:

```
def my_encode(s):
    return ''.join(
        c if 0x20 <= ord(c) <= 0x7E else r'\u%04x' % ord(c)
        for c in s
    )
```

For each character in the string, if the code point is between 0x20 and 0x7E, then that character remains unchanged; otherwise, `\u` followed by the code point encoded as a 4-digit hex number is used.  The expression `c for c in s` is a *generator* expression, so we convert that back into a string using [`str.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) on the empty string.

For decoding, you can just use the `unicode_escape` codec as you mentioned:

```
def my_decode(s):
    return s.decode('unicode_escape')
```

Comment: This only works if the input is a Unicode string. Don't try to pass UTF-8! The output will be an ASCII string so it would work either way.